# How to use the useSound hook with multiple audio files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I'm trying to play a different mp3 sound on hover and then stop the sound when the mouse leaves. I installed the use-sound library but I can't figure out how to use it with more than one audio file.

If I rename the play function into playAudio1 for example I can make useSound play the right audio file, but I can't figure out how to stop the correct audio file. I was thinking is there a way to assign the "stop" function in each hook to a different variable name, so I can reference it below in the onMouseLeave event.

The code below gives me an error because I have two identical "stop" functions.

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import Audio1 from "../public/mp3/audio1.mp3";
import Audio2 from "../public/mp3/audio2.mp3";
import useSound from "use-sound";

function Home() {
   const [hoverAudio1, setHoverAudio1] = useState(false);
   const [hoverAudio2, setHoverAudio2] = useState(false);

   const [playAudio1, { stop }] = useSound(Audio1, {
    volume: 0.5,
   });
   const [playAudio2, { stop }] = useSound(Audio2, {
    volume: 0.5,
   });

   return (
      <div
          onMouseEnter={() => {
            setHoverAudio1(true);
            playAudio1();
          }}
          onMouseLeave={() => {
            setHoverAudio1(false);
            stop();
          }}
        >
      </div>
      <div
          onMouseEnter={() => {
            setHoverAudio2(true);
            playAudio2();
          }}
          onMouseLeave={() => {
            setHoverAudio2(false);
            stop();
          }}
        >
      </div>
    )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `[playAudio1, {stop}]` you should use `[playAudio1, stopAudio1]` to get the return values from the hook. Then you can access the stop function with `stopAudio1.stop()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename destructured keys:

```
const [playAudio1, { stop: stopAudio1 }] = useSound(Audio1, {
  volume: 0.5,
});

const [playAudio2, { stop: stopAudio2 }] = useSound(Audio2, {
  volume: 0.5,
});

return (
    <div
        onMouseEnter={() => {
            setHoverAudio1(true);
            playAudio1();
        }}
        onMouseLeave={() => {
            setHoverAudio1(false);
            stopAudio1();
        }}
    ></div>
    <div
        onMouseEnter={() => {
            setHoverAudio2(true);
            playAudio2();
        }}
        onMouseLeave={() => {
            setHoverAudio2(false);
            stopAudio2();
        }}
    ></div>
);
```